# Problem with pagination when using leftJoinAndMapMany and orderBy typeOrm

Tags: node.js, pagination, typeorm

I have problem when using pagination  typeOrm. This is my query builder code:

```
const query = this.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndMapMany(
        'user.timelogs',
        Timelog,
        'timelog',
        'user.code = timelog.userCode',
      )
      .select([
        'user.id',
        'timelog.id',
        'timelog.projectCode',
        'timelog.logHour',
        'timelog.checkDate',
      ]);
      // .orderBy('timelog.checkDate', 'ASC', 'NULLS LAST')
```

When I using this code without orderBy, the pagination work well.
This is the result without orderBy, the first user had 4 timelogs

[image]

This is the result with orderBy, the result lost 2 users:

[image]

Edit: when I change orderBy to timelog.logHour, timelog.projectCode, timelog.logHour, ... each case will lost 0-3 users. I do not understand

Case timelog.id lost 3 users:
[image]
Case timelog.project code lost 1 users:
[image]
Case timelog.logHour had full user:
[image]

This is my entity:

```
@Entity({ name: 'timelogs' })
    export class Timelog extends AbstractEntity {
      @Column({ name: 'user_code', nullable: false })
      userCode: string;
    
      @Column({ name: 'project_code', nullable: false })
      projectCode: string;
    
      @Column({ name: 'log_hour', type: 'float4', default: 0 })
      logHour: number;
    
      @Column({ name: 'description', nullable: true })
      description: string;
    
      @Column({ name: 'check_date', type: 'date' })
      checkDate: Date;
    }
```

What can i do to fix this. Thank for your attention.